# Show Greek Date in English Format

Tags: excel, vba

If I use

```
now()
```

in VBA I get in my system with Greek locale:

```
5/9/2014 10:24:20 πμ
```

What code can I use in VBA so that the date always return in english format?

Comment: Try `Format(Now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM")`

Comment: I think you mean `Format(Now,"dd/mm/yyyy h:Nn:Ss AM/PM")` per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755(v=office.15).aspx) (if you want the leading 0 on the hour it is `Hh` instead of just `h`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `[$-F800]` for English(US) locale as prefix for the format text. The full formula is `Format(Now,"[$-F800]dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")`

You can search the right locale prefix in Format Cell Dialog Box by switching back between Date/Time/Special and Custom and choosing different locale.

For example locale prefix for Greek is `[$-408]`, Chinese is `[$-C04]`, and so on